# Carousel using jQuery 'index' function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JavaScript:

```
$("nav ul li").click(function (){
    var index = $(this).attr('value');
    $("#pages").css('left', index + '%');
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="about" class="selected inSelected" value="50">About</li>
        <li id="contact" value="-50">Contact</li>
        <li id="test" value="-150">YouTube</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The code above does what I need it to do. Imagine a div in the middle of the page (left 50%). As you click a item in the list it shuffles it along by the 'value' attribute. Eg, clicking YouTube would set the left to -150% essentially moving the div along to other content.

My problem with this is it's not very efficient but my non-mathematical brain isn't helping me come up with a sensible solution. I want to achieve the same thing but without having to set specific values for each li. This should be more than possible use 'index()'.

```
$("nav ul li").click(function (){
    var index = $(this).index(); // this is the main difference
});
```

Let's say you click YouTube, index will be equal to 2. So now I need to get from 2 to -150. Fine, that's possible, but I need to use the exact same formula to get back to Contact with index 1.

If anyone could help I'd highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("nav ul li").click(function (){
    var index = $(this).index(); // this is the main difference
    var value = index * -100 + 50
});
```

like

```
index calc            value
0 =   0 * -100 + 50 = 50
1 =   1 * -100 + 50 = -50
2 =   2 * -100 + 50 = -150
3 =   3 * -100 + 50 = -250
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r23pX/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I struggle to see why I couldn't see this myself!